# Is this an easter egg in the Etherscan Api?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, python

Ethereum (and so, the etherscan.io API), operate with 160-bit addresses. However, I unintentionally requested the max address (0xFF...FF) **and** I padded it with leading zeros (to become 0x00..00FF...FF), so it kind of became a malformed value because with the leading zeros the number now has more than 160 bits. The transactions that came out are interesting. Nothing *should* come out, as the chance that a "random" address exists is zero (x/2^160, where x is the total number of addresses).
I needed to play a bit with hex or byte mappings, but two of the transactions that came out are the quote "Great works are performed not by strength but by perseverance" and the initial digits of the number Pi. Normally, transactions should contain binary data, starting with the hash of the signature of the function that needs to be called in the contract. That's not really interesting as anyone can send transactions and put whatever in them, but afaik there shouldn't be a difference between a 160-bit address and the the same address with leading zeros? The latter should even be illegal? e.g. The Goerli etherscan testnet api behaves as if the leading zeros weren't there (with normal contract addresses).

The screenshot contains all the information needed for reproduction. The number of leading zeros does not matter, but it should be even (e.g. two zeros and then 40 F's). When I change anything else in the address such as omitting all leading zeros, these transactions do not show up.

[image: screenshot etherscan API call]

The Python code, if anyone needs it:

```
import configparser

import requests


class ContractNotFoundException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message="Contract not found"):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)


class ContractBytecodeFetcher:
    urls = None

    def __init__(self, config_location="../../../config.ini"):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(config_location)
        self.urls = [
            dict(api_base_url='https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/api', key=config["DEFAULT"]["etherscan_api_key"]),
            dict(api_base_url='https://api.etherscan.io/api', key=config["DEFAULT"]["etherscan_api_key"]),
            dict(api_base_url='https://api.bscscan.com/api', key=config["DEFAULT"]["bsc_scan_api_key"]),
        ]

    def fetch_etherscan_first_transaction(self, contract_address):
        for url in self.urls:
            params = {
                "module": "account",
                "action": "txlist",
                "address": ("0x" + contract_address.hex()) if isinstance(contract_address, bytes) else contract_address,
                "startblock": "0",
                "endblock": "99999999",  # some arbitrarily large number to cover all blocks
                "page": 1,
                "offset": 0,
                "sort": "asc",  # to ensure we get the earliest transactions first
                "apikey": url['key']
            }

            response = requests.get(url['api_base_url'], params=params)

            if response.status_code != 200:
                raise Exception("API request failed with status code", response.status_code)

            json_response = response.json()

            if json_response["status"] == "1":
                transactions = json_response["result"]
                if not transactions:
                    raise ContractNotFoundException("No transactions found for contract")

                return bytes.fromhex(transactions[0]['input'][2:])
        raise ContractNotFoundException("Contract not found")
```